# Setup project 2017 not removing previous version of setup project 2015

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, installation, setup-deployment

So, i have been using setup project 2015 for Visual studio and it has been working fine. It installs my application and removes older versions.

I recently decided to start using Visual Studio 2017, which is incompatible with setup project 2015. So, i upgraded to Setup project 2017, Added a new setup project to my solution and used all the same settings from the 2015 one.

Although, when i install my application, it removes previous versions of the 2017 installer, not the 2015. So if you install my application with the 2015 msi, and then with the 2017 msi, you will have 1 version in your control panel(the newest one), but if you launch the application it's the old 2015 MSI version.

Copying the `UpgradeCode` to the 2017 installer also didn't work

Any solution to this? :/ (It's not a `RemovePreviousVersions = true` issue or anything.

Edit: it also goes from 16MB to 10MB(control panel), but if i manually remove the old version and install the new version, it's 16mb in size

Answer (score 2):

Settings `BackwardCompatibleIDGeneration` to `true` worked for me